# Taurus. Reusing common scenario with different variables

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, taurus

Taurus allows me combine scenarios like this

```
scenarios:
  create-bob-account:
    requests:
    - url: http://example.com/account/create
      method: POST
      body:
        account_owner: bob
        account_number: 123
  create-lisa-account:
    requests:
    - url: http://example.com/account/create
      method: POST
      body:
        account_owner: lisa
        account_number: 321
  account-transfer:
    requests:
    - include-scenario: create-bob-account
    - include-scenario: create-bob-account
    - url: http://example.com/transfer
      method: POST
      body:
        account_number_from: 123
        account_number_to: 321
   ...
```

In this example i have duplicate code that creates info about accout bob and lisa. Can i parametrize an **create-account** scenario? I.e. create script

```
scenarios:
  create-account:
    requests:
    - url: http://example.com/account/create
      method: POST
      body:
        account_owner: ${owner}
        account_number: ${number}
```

and call it with different variables, something like this

```
scenarios:
  account-transfer:
    requests:
    - include-scenario: 
         arugment: bob, 123
         create-account 
      - include-scenario: 
         arugment: lisa, 321
         create-account 
    - url: http://example.com/transfer
```

Maybe there is some way to implement this functionality? 
The basic idea is to identify scripts that are independent of specific variables and reuse them in various scripts with the variables that are needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)? This way you can put your account names and IDs into a CSV file and include the request block to read these name/id combination from the CSV file, the relevant Taurus directives are [`data-sources`](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Data-sources) and [`include-scenarios`](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Include-Scenario-Blocks)

Example YAML config:

```
execution:
  - scenario: account-transfer

scenarios:
  account-create:
    data-sources:
      - details.csv
    requests:
      - url: http://example.com/account/create
        method: POST
        body:
          account_owner: ${account_owner}
          account_number: ${account_number}
  account-transfer:
    requests:
      - include-scenario: account-create
      - include-scenario: account-create
      - url: http://example.com/transfer
        method: POST
        body:
          account_number_from: 123
          account_number_to: 321
```